# JPA persistent class extending another class from different JAR

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence

Hoping someone can helpme with this issue as all the answers I have found do not seem to be working for me.

Under my myProj webapp I have the following

```
./WEB=INF/lib/myproj-user.jar containing this class

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class UserDetails extends CommonObject {
    ...
}
```

.

```
./WEB=INF/lib/myproj-common.jar containing this class

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommonObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -980608025624315940L;

    @Getter @Setter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

And my application-context.xml has this *(application-context.xml has sub XMLs called hibernate-context and model-context.xml, but these have always been fine)*

```
<bean id="commonAuto" class="com.myproj.common.model.CommonObject"/>
<bean id="userDetails" class="com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.myproj.common.model.CommonObject</value>             
            <value>com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails</value>
```

But on startup I get the following error in my logs

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.myproj.user.dao.UserDao
>   com.myproj.user.servces.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userAccountDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.myproj.user.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/context/hibernate-context.xml]: **Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   No identifier specified for entity: com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails**
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4323)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4780)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:785)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:763)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:557)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:540)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1390)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:355)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:996)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:988)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:427)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415) Caused
>   by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.myproj.user.dao.UserDao
>   com.myproj.user.servces.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userAccountDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.myproj.user.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/context/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   No identifier specified for entity: com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>     ... 45 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userAccountDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.myproj.user.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/context/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   No identifier specified for entity: com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
>     ... 47 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.myproj.user.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/context/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   No identifier specified for entity: com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>     ... 58 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/context/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   No identifier specified for entity: com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
>     ... 60 more Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No
>   identifier specified for entity: com.myproj.user.model.UserDetails    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:276)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:665)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3431)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3385)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1727)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
>     ... 70 more

Comment: Add an `@Id` annotation to your id property.

Comment: Todd - Just one second whilst I go out the room and scream!!!!! Seriously how the hell did I miss that! The commonObject class is taken from an old app I wrote. Must have deleted the @Id by mistake and just not looked properly. :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
  @MappedSuperclass
  public abstract class CommonObject implements Serializable {
      private Date createDate;
      public abstract Long getId() ;
      public abstract void setId(Long id);

      public Date getCreateDate() {
            return createDate;
      }

      public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
            this.createDate = createDate;
      } 
  }



   @Entity
   @Table
   public class UserDetails extends CommonObject {

        String name;
        int age;

         @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
         @Id
         private Long id;
         public String getName() {
                 return name;
         }

         public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
         }

         public int getAge() {
               return age;
         }

         public void setAge(int age) {
                this.age = age;
         }

         public Long getId() {
                 return id;
         }

         public void setId(Long id) {
             this.id = id;
         }
   }
```